# Pop over doesn't point over the button

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, popover

I have an application that is compatible with both iPhone and iPad layouts. For iPhone layout I have created Action Sheet and Pop over for iPad. The problem is pop over's arrow does not point over the button I clicked. Below is my code....

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose an option",
            message: "Message",
            preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
...

if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad
{
     // for iPad
     actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
     actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.bounds;
     actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros;
}

self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Set the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` as the `button` and `button.bounds`. 
You can choose the permittedArrowDirections depending on the layout of your view.

```
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = button.bounds;
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Left;
```

If the button is a BarButtonItem use this code.

```
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = button
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up;
```

Comment: Ok that didn't work either. The button is actually a `UIBarButtonItem`. I have changed the function as `@IBAction func userOptions(button: UIBarButtonItem)` and it throwed an error: `[UIBarButtonItem bounds]: unrecognized selector sent`

Comment: check my modified answer @SrujanSimha

Comment: What's the difference between sourceView and sourceRect?

Comment: Using `bounds` instead of `frame` is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For me worked using the sender and casting as UIView.

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as! UIView
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds

alertController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 3**

This worked for me when my button was a UIBarButtonItem:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

    if controller.responds(to: "popoverPresentationController") {
        controller.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = YourUIBarButtonName
    }

}
```

Entire code snippet below:

```
func presentActivitySheet() {

    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [document.fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

            if controller.responds(to: "popoverPresentationController") {
            controller.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = YourUIBarButtonName
            }

        }

    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```