# Swift Present Popover View from a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

**Question**

Hello. How, in Swift, do I present a popover from a  Storyboard-created UIButton, in order to get photos from the photo library? I have figured out the photos library stuff, just not the presenting of the view controller.

**Research**

I found instructions on how to do a similar thing from a BarButtonItem about half way down [here](http://makeapppie.com/2014/12/04/swift-swift-using-the-uiimagepickercontroller-for-a-camera-and-photo-library/).

**Current Attempts**

I am trying the following code.

```
self.imagePicker.delegate = self
self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            
self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)//4
self.imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.photo = sender
```

with `photo` being the UIButton that I want to present this modal view from. For simplicity's sake, only the parts of the code related to presenting the view are given.

I have also tried

```
self.imagePicker.delegate = self
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            
            self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
            self.imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = self.photo.bounds
            self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

which gives a sigabrt,

**Action**

When the above code is typed, Xcode gives the error

> "use of unresolved identifier 'sender'"

**Expected Action**

I want a popover containing the photo library to be presented, as shown in this image:

[image: Expected Behavior]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is sender defined in this code block?

Comment: @Msencenb No. How do I do that?

Comment: The last line in that code references a 'sender' variable. Often that's used with IBOutlets, but the error means sender is not defined.

Comment: maybe something like this?
`self.imagePicker.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = photo.bounds`

Comment: @Lucho I get a sigabrt when I do that

Comment: @rocket101 here is another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823211/pop-over-doesnt-point-over-the-button) with something similar. maybe adding `actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = photo` does photo is different of nil?

Comment: @Lucho It works!!! Thanks so much - if you post that as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Oh man, now I want a Pizza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the source view of popover like this

```
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = photo
```

Hope it helps.